# Load an image from HTTP Response

Tags: android, json, kotlin, qr-code, rapidapi

I am using an API to make custom QR codes in my android app. I have used [this](https://rapidapi.com/qrcode-monkey/api/custom-qr-code-with-logo) api. Now, to get the QR code, I used this code:

```kotlin
val client = OkHttpClient()

val mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/json")

val body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, "{ " +
                    "\"data\": \"https://google.com\", " +
                    "\"config\": {" +
                    "\"body\": \"circular\"," +
                    "\"eyeBall\": \"ball15\"," +
                    "\"logo\": \"https://storage.googleapis.com/support-kms-prod/ZAl1gIwyUsvfwxoW9ns47iJFioHXODBbIkrK\" " +
                    "}," +
                    "\"size\": 500," +
                    "\"download\": false," +
                    "\"file\": \"png\" " +
                    "}")

val request = Request.Builder()
                .url("https://qrcode-monkey.p.rapidapi.com/qr/custom")
                .post(body)
                .addHeader("content-type", "application/json")
                .addHeader("X-RapidAPI-Host", "qrcode-monkey.p.rapidapi.com")
                .addHeader("X-RapidAPI-Key", "API_KEY")
                .build()

val response = client.newCall(request).execute()
```

Now, from here, I dont know how to get that image and load it in an image view. I think Glide can be used but I dont have any idea about that.

Comment: https://square.github.io/okhttp/recipes/

Comment: @blackapps thanks for that. But, can you share the code for that

Comment: Oh. so it is the same as JSoup right @blackapps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed the discussion on the [QR Code Monkey Discussion](https://rapidapi.com/qrcode-monkey/api/custom-qr-code-with-logo/discussions/20642)

We need to set the  “download” parameter to “imageUrl”,  so that in the response we will get the url response for the QR .

We can simply load that url in the Glide by following snippets of code :

```
  Glide.with(this).load(IMAGE_URL_FROM_RESPONSE).into(yourImageView);
```

Comment: That url is invalid.

Comment: Please  share the response and URL

Comment: Not that. The url you have provided on the top is invalid. It is in the first line. Click and see.

Comment: I have edited and added a valid link .

Comment: Im not sure why it is not working. Maybe because I have not purchased the api. I only have the free one which does not work

Comment: Initially, i think you have hide the api key while asking question. You need to add API_Key on  this paameter ("X-RapidAPI-Key", "API_KEY") which you wil get after purchasing. If the loading pic using glide section helps, please upvote my answer and mark it as accepted. Thanks

Comment: Well, I purchased the API, and it works perfectly. Thanks.